# Python: list comprehension strange behaviour

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why is this code:

```
x = {"first":(True, "first description"), "second":(False, "second description")}
items = ["first", "second"]

for element in [k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]:
    print element
```

printing

- True
- False

instead of the elements in the "items"-list that match the expression

```
k in x and x[k][0]
```

Comment: Because `x and x[k][0]` does **not** concatenate... The `and` operator returns the first element whose *truthiness* is `False` (or the last element if none is `False`).

Comment: Because `k in x and x[k][0]` evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: If you want the output `first` then `second`, you just need `for e in items: print e`

Comment: Move the condition to the end of the comprehension: `for element in [k for k in items if k in x and x[k][0]]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I'm not sure what you mean by *concatenate* there. How would changing the `and` operator to a non-lazy boolean operator change the output to match the expected output? The issue here appears to be that the OP is expecting the list comprehension to filter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well based on the question, the OP might *think* that the `and` operator concats, so that it enumerates *for every `k` in `x` and `x[k][0]`. That is of course not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the outcome of the expression `k in x and x[k][0]`.

That's either going to be `False` (if the outcome of the `k in x` condition is false), or the outcome of `x[k][0]` (if the outcome of `k in x` was true). Since `x[k][0]` is a boolean object in your input sample, you'll always get boolean values here; nowhere will the list comprehension produce the keys instead.

If you wanted to *filter*, use an `if` statement after the loop:

```
[k for k in items if k in x and x[k][0]]
```

This then produces a list with `k` values for which the expression produces true, which for your sample data matches *just one element*, `['first']`, because only for that key is the first element in the tuple set to `True`.

Answer (score 3):

`[k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]` returns the boolean expression `k in x and x[k][0]` for every element in `items`, which will be True for every element whose first element is truthy.

What you probably mean is:

```
[k for k in items if k in x and x[k][0]]
```

Comment: Hmm, the OP wants `first` and `second`. It looks like your solution will print just `first`

Comment: @quamrana: we are guessing at what they want here, both interpretations are valid at this point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, we are in desperate need of a reply from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {"first":(True, "first description"), "second":(False, "second description")}
items = ["first", "second"]

for element in [k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]:
    print element
```

Lets try to understand what result it gives you from the list comprehension.

```
[k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]
```

Lets observe it from the right side. for k in items == ['first', 'second']

**1st iteration**

k = 'first'

['first' in x (True) and x['first'][0] (True)]

[True and True]

[True]

**2nd Iteration**

k = 'second'

list is [True]

[True, 'second' in x (True) and x['second'][0] (False)]

[True, True and False]

[True, False]

Now,

```
for element in [True, False]:
    print element
```

It should print,

True

False

which is what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `expression` to generate new list in `[k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]` is `k in x and x[k][0]`, and the evaluation of `and` process is that it'll split the whole expression by `and`, then evaluate each `"sub-expression"`, return the first `falsy` value or the last value no matter whatever it is. In this case it'll first evaluate `k in x`, which will always be `true`, then it will return the result of `x[k][0]`, which generates the final result:

> `[True, False]`

If you try `[k in x and x[k][0] for k in items]`, you'll get result:

> ['first description', 'second description']

To filter element, you need to put the test condition at the tail of the whole expression like:

```
[k for k in items if k in x and x[k][0]]
```